# Find which dictionaries from a list contain word

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, dictionary

I have a dictionary with each keys having multiple values in a list. 
The tasks are:

1. To detect whether a given word is in the dictionary values
2. If it is true, then return the respective key from the dictionary

Task 1 is achieved by using an if condition:

```
if (word in dictionary[topics] for topics in dictionary.keys())
```

I want to get the topics when the if condition evaluates to be True. Something like

```
if (word in dictionary[topics] for topics in dictionary.keys()):
   print topics
```

Comment: Take a look at "list comprehensions" (cheesey-looking tutorial [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk))

Comment: Thanks @PaulRichter that tutorial is very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension (which is like a compressed `for` loop). They are simpler to write and can in some circumstances be faster to compute:

```
topiclist = [topic for topic in dictionary if word in dictionary[topic]]
```

You don't need `dictionary.keys()` because a `dict` is already an iterable object; iterating over it will yield the keys anyway, and (in Python 2) in a more efficient way than `dictionary.keys()`.

**EDIT:**
Here is another way to approach this (it avoids an extra dictionary look up):

```
topiclist = [topic for (topic, tlist) in dictionary.items() if word in tlist]
```

Avoiding the extra dictionary lookup may make it faster, although I haven't tested it.

In Python 2, for efficiency sake, you may want to do:

```
topiclist = [topic for (topic, tlist) in dictionary.iteritems() if word in tlist]
```

Comment: If the word appears more than once in values, I'm just using the first element of result, `topiclist[0]` to get the first value. or is there any pythonic way to stop once the if condition evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @blueBeetle: You can use a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension. It is lazily evaluated. It requires a bit more to safely extract from the generator if it happens to not find anything, whereas the list only requires a simple check like `if topiclist: # then do something` since lists are "true" if they contain any values. Generators work a bit different, since they are lazily evaluated. Extracting a single element from a generator requires a `try/except` statement in case the generator is empty. I can add generator comprehension as an added example if you would like.

Comment: @blueBeetle: Or if you just want the first match, a simple `for` loop may be best. I can add that to the answer as well if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (word in dictionary[topics] for topics in dictionary.keys())
```

the problem with the above line is that you are creating a generator object that assesses whether `word` is in each value of `dictionary` and returning a bool for each. Since non-empty lists are always true, this if statement will ALWAYS be true, regardless if the word is in the values or not. you can do 2 things:

- using `any()` will make your `if` statement work:

  ```
  if any(word in dictionary[topics] for topics in dictionary.keys()):
  ```

however, this does not solve your initial problem of capturing the key value. so instead:

- use an actual list comprehension that uses the predefined (I assume) variable `word` as a filter of sorts:

  ```
  keys = [topics for topics in dictionary if word in dictionary[topics]]
  ```

or

- use `filter()`

  ```
  keys = filter(lambda key: word in dictionary[key],dictionary)
  ```

these both do the same thing. reminder that iterating through `dictionary` and `dictionary.keys()` are equivalent

just a note that both these methods return a list of all the keys that have values containing `word`. Access each key with regular list item getting.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the word you are searching for will be found in only one key. Correct?

If so, you can just iterate over the dictionary's key-value pairs until you find the key that contains the search word.

For Python 2:

```
found = False
for (topic, value) in dictionary.iteritems():
    if word in topic:
        found = True
        print topic
        break
```

For Python 3, just replace `iteritems()` with `items()`.