# How do I search Values in a dictionary which are lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following line of code:

```
food_web = {'Limpets ': [' Seaweed'],'Zooplankton ': ['Phytoplankton'],'Fish':[' Prawn'],'Whelk ': [' Limpets', ' Mussels'],'Lobster ': [' Crab', ' Mussels', ' Limpets', ' Whelk']}
```

I want to determine an apex predator, which would mean a key that does not appear in any values of the dictionary, so I need to search for each key in all the values but I've got no idea how to approach this.The values are list as well which makes things difficult for me.  I am just learning python so my knowledge may well be below par..

Comment: There are several existing questions on Stack Overflow that can help you read a list of lists in Python. Start there and then tell us where you get stuck (include code).

Comment: like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004185/find-which-dictionaries-from-a-list-contain-word/34004535#34004535) which grabs all the keys that has values that contain a certain word. I feel like (although not quite a duplicate) this question is very applicable to what you need

Comment: @Praise, what is the deal with the whitespace?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've edited the question. is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean are the spaces there or not

Comment: Yes the spaces are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would probably be to combine all of the values into a single list:

```
values = [item.strip() for subl in food_web.values() for item in subl]
```

Let's look at this line from the inside out:

`food_web.values()` is a list of all of the `values` in the dictionary.  So it's a list of lists.  I want to extract all of the values inside the inner-lists, so I'm adding another 'comprehension': `for item in subl`.  Together, this takes each of the sub-lists in `food_web.values()` and extracts each element.  It then puts all of those (individual) elements back together into a single list.

I'm using the `strip()` command to remove the extra whitespace which will make string-comparisons more difficult.

You can then check to see if the `items` exist in this new list:

```
for kk in food_web.keys():
    if kk.strip() not in values:
        print("Apex: ", kk)
```

Comment: this is a nice clean answer and doesn't rely on any advanced concepts - sets are confusing to newbees

Comment: @gkusner, using a set would hardly advanced but it is significantly more efficient than doing a `O(n)` scan that you have to do using a list, you also don't need to call .keys to iterate over the keys of a dict

Comment: i would say if you have to include itertools its advanced for someone like the questioner - but thats just my 2 cents

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix thanks this worked well for me, just curious but is there a different way of writing the first part , values?

Comment: @PraiseOkwa yeah - totally, I've added an edit to expound a little.  Let me know if that's still unclear at all.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Thanks that helped

Answer (score 5):

I have a concise solution, but it only works if the keys and values are character-for-character identical, so you'll have to strip off the spaces at the beginnings and ends of your strings first.

```
food_web = {
    'Limpets': ['Seaweed'],
    'Zooplankton': ['Phytoplankton'],
    'Fish': ['Prawn'],
    'Whelk': ['Limpets', 'Mussels'],
    'Lobster': ['Crab', 'Mussels', 'Limpets', 'Whelk']
}

print set(food_web.keys()) - set().union(*food_web.values())
```

Result:

```
set(['Zooplankton', 'Fish', 'Lobster'])
```

---

A little more explanation: `set.union()` takes all of its arguments and combines them into one set. The asterisk [unpacks](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the elements of `food_web.values()` into individual arguments. Subtracting two sets gives a set of all the items in the first set that aren't in the second.

Comment: could you explain what set and set().union is and what they do? i get a syntax error trying to run it.

Comment: @PraiseOkwa You're probably using Python 3. Surround the whole expression after `print` in parentheses.

Comment: @PraiseOkwa, You removed the spaces first, right? Because `" Limpets"` and `"Limpets "` will be considered different animals.

Comment: @Kevin yes i did. All strings in the dictionary are written as "Limpets"

Answer (score 0):

create a set of all the values, stripping the whitespace and iterate over the keys also stripping and checking if the key is in the set of values:

```
from itertools import chain
vals = set(s.strip() for s in chain.from_iterable(food_web.values()))


for k in food_web:
    if k.strip() not in vals:
        print(k)
```

Which outputs:

```
Lobster 
Zooplankton 
Fish
```

If the keys and values did not have extra whitespace you could use `dict.viewkeys` in python 2 or just `.keys` in python3:

```
# food_web.keys()  python3
print(food_web.viewkeys() - chain.from_iterable(food_web.values()))
```

which would give:

```
set(['Lobster', 'Zooplankton', 'Fish'])
```

but that only works for identical strings which yours are not.

If you want to first tidy up your keys and values then viewkeys would work and you will have a more memory efficient solution:

```
for k,v in food_web.items():
    food_web[k] = [x.strip() for x in v]

print(food_web.viewkeys() - chain.from_iterable(food_web.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
[key1 for key1 in food_web if not any([key1 in value for key2, value in food_web.items()])]
```

the following is a nested comprehension.
The presence of keys from the outer comprehension is being checked in the inner one. This returns the list of booleans. Evaluating the any function on this list returns true, only if any of the elements in the list is true. Therefore this expression returns the collection of keys none of which are present in the values of the given dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is best to give an explanation of your answer, rather than offering a code-only answer. The explanation will make your answer much more clear to the OP and will help others who may benefit.